# Provide default data in collection child form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a nested form with prototype feature in Symfony 2. Here is the parent form which contains the collection:

```
$builder
        ->add('rooms', 'collection', array(
            'type'          => new RoomForm(),
            'allow_add'     => true,
            'allow_delete'  => true,
            'data'          => array(new RoomForm()),
        ))
```

As you can see, no `data_class` is defined. After the form submission `$form->getData()` correctly return associative array.

`RoomForm` is a simple form class composed by two fields:

```
$builder
        ->add(
            $builder->create('dateAvailabilityStart', 'text', array(
                'label'             => 'label.from'
         )))
        ->add(
            $builder->create('dateAvailabilityEnd', 'text', array(
                'label'             => 'label.until'
        )))
```

I would like find a way to populate my collection with existing `RoomForm` (for edit mode) and associate data in correct fields.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it from within your controller. Given that above form type is named as `RoomFormCollection` you could do something like this:

```
// This should be an array
$rooms = ... // Either from database or...

$form = $this->createForm(new RoomFormCollection(), array(
    'rooms' => rooms
));
```

Another thing, `'data' => array(new RoomForm()),` is not valid. `RoomForm` as its name suggests is a form type, not data struct. You should remove it...

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I removed `data` attribute from my parent class and passed the collection from my controller.

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)